# Showing a group where $\forall x,y \in G$, $x^{2}$ and $y$ commute is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotence

This is related to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507140/if-g-is-a-group-such-that-any-two-commutators-commute-g-is-solvable) I asked yesterday.

Let $G$ be a group such that for every $x$, $y$ $\in G$, the elements $x^{2}$ and $y$ commute.  I need to show that $G$ is nilpotent.

This is what I have so far:

> Since $\forall x,\,y \in G$, the elements $x^{2}$ and $y$ commute,
>   $\{x^{2}\} \in C(G)$, the center of $G$.
>
> Now, $G_{0} = G$, $G_{1}=G/C(G)=\{\text{elements of the form}\,zC(G),\,\text{where}z\in G\}$.

But, **1) I'm not sure if $x^{2}$ is even all of $C(G)$** (there could be other elements in $G$ that also commute) or even how to show that it is if in fact it is. Also, **2) If I have it done right so far, how do I figure out what $G_{2}$ is, and whether or not it is trivial?**

I say that this problem is related to the other one I asked about because showing that a group is nilpotent or solvable **both kind of deal with looking at quotient groups/cosets, and I still don't entirely understand those.**

Could somebody help me with this, and in the process, help me to understand? **Pretend like you're trying to explain this to somebody who is incredibly clueless,** because that is exactly how I feel right now.

Comment: You don't know that $y \in C(G)$. If that was true then $G$ would be abelian! What you know is that $x^2 \in C(G)$ for all $x \in G$. So what does that tell you about the quotient group $G/C(G)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt, yeahI just realized this. About to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the subgroup $N=\langle x^2 : x \in G \rangle$. Then $N$ is central and $G/N$ is abelian, since every element has order $2$ in this quotient. Hence $G' \subseteq N$, so $\gamma_3(G)=[G',G]=1$ and $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: THANK YOU! Can you show me explicitly that every element in $G/N$ is order 2? I'd like to better be able to visualize it. Also, $x^{2}$ is normal b/c it's Abelian, right?

Comment: not to keep bugging you, but I am unfamiliar with the terminology $\gamma_{3}(G)$. Is it the same thing that I would call $G_{2}$, based on what I wrote above?

Comment: Every element of $G/N$ has order $2$ ($(xN)^2=x^2N=N$ for $x^2 \in N$) and it is well known and easy to prove that in general for a group in which every element has order $2$, then it is abelian. Now $N$ is normal since $g^{-1}x^2g=(g^{-1}xg)^2$, so conjugates of squares are again squares.

Comment: In general, $\gamma_i(G)=[G,\gamma_{i-1}(G)]$ is the $i$-th term of the *lower central series*, a concept that is normally explained in connection to nilpotency. The lower central series reaches  $\{1\}$ iff $G$ is nilpotent. See for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series

Comment: I see. We were only told about the upper central series.

Comment: OK, different proof ($N$ as I defined), $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, since $G' \subseteq N \subseteq Z(G)$. Hence $Z(G/Z(G))=Z_2(G)/Z(G)=G/Z(G)$, so $G=Z_2(G)$, and you are done.