# Let $H = \langle X \rangle$ then $H' = \langle [x_1, x_2]^h \mid x_1, x_2 \in X, h \in H \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derived-subgroup

> Let $H = \langle X \rangle$, then $$H' = \langle [x_1, x_2]^h \mid x_1, x_2 \in X, h \in H \rangle.$$

Obviously $$\langle [x_1, x_2]^h \mid x_1, x_2 \in X, h \in H \rangle \leq H'.$$ Any tips on how to proceed are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the subgroup is normal and the quotient abelian.

Comment: I think this post [Generators of the first commutator subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705248) contains an answer to this question.